# Remove NaNs from a data set and set casting type

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is following: I want to prepare a data set for Tensorflow and need to get rid of Nans.
But when I turn it into an array the Nans are still there even after running .dropna() or .fillna().

The error it throws it that it cannot remove the errors because of the casting type and as a result I cannot use the split function.
Can anybody explain to me why this casting type is preventing me from deleting the Nans?
**Python version: 3.7**

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Oct 24 12:01:09 2019

@author: bill-
"""

#load the transaction data and all packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#%%
#switching the backslashes to slashes
link = r"C:\Users\bill-\Desktop\TransactionsD.csv"
new_link = link.replace(os.sep, '/')
file = ''.join(('', new_link,''))

#load the data and skip the first row, then rename the columns to something informative
#columns
#date = date of transaction
#trans_cat = category of transaction
#subcat = subcategory
#shopname = shop name
#amount = amount in USD
#####
#index_col = None uses first column automatically
#index_col = False uses no index at all
data = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 1, index_col = False, na_values = 0,  names = ['date',
                                                                   'category',
                                                                   'trans_cat',
                                                                   'subcat',
                                                                   'shopname',
                                                                   'amount'])

#%%
#LabelEncoder for category, trans_cat, shopname
#use the LabelEncoder to make shopname numerical
LE = LabelEncoder()
data['LE_shopname'] = LE.fit_transform(data['shopname'])
#this one doesnt work
data['LE_category'] = LE.fit_transform(data['category'])

#category does not support conversion of strings; is being converted to numbers and then to integers values
#change to categorical data which also does not allow me to remove NaNs
#data['category'] = pd.Categorical(data['category'])
#change to float number AND drop all kinds of NaNs for potential preprocessing
#KEEP COPY TRUE TO AVOID BREAKING INHERITED FEATURES!
data['category'].fillna(value = 0)
data['category'] = data['category'].astype('float32', copy = True, errors = 'raise')

#do not create a new column but change the old one
data['LE_category'] = data.replace(to_replace={'category': {'nan': 0},
                                                'category': {'Shops': 1},
                                                'category': {'Food and Drink': 2},
                                                'category': {'Travel': 3},
                                                'category': {'Service': 4},
                                                'category': {'Transfer': 5},
                                                'category': {'Community': 6},
                                                'category': {'Bank Fees': 7},
                                                'category': {'Recreation': 8}},
                                                value = None)

#READY UP DATA TO BE READY FOR FEATURES AND PASS IT TO TENSOR FLOW
data_features = data.drop(['date', 'trans_cat','subcat', 'shopname', 'LE_shopname'], axis = 1)
#convert it to an array to make it a feature
model_features = data_features.to_numpy(dtype = 'float32', copy = True)
#no labels to see if tensor can handle the input
model_label = data['LE_shopname'].to_numpy(dtype = 'float32', copy = True)
#%%
#INPUT: PANDAS DATA FRAMER
#OUTPUT: OBJECT TYPE THAT CANT BE USED FOR FURTHER OPERATIONS IF IT IS NOT CONVERTED TO A DATA FRAME AGAIN


#%%
#train_test_split seems to take 2 times the identical data frame
#DATA_FEATURES=LOADED TRANSACTION DATA
#category       category
#subcat          float64
#amount          float64
#LE_shopname       int32

#Equation: category + subcategory + amount ~ LE_shopname

#splitting of the data
#look up structure of train test split; since x= and y=  doesnt work sometimes
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(model_features, model_label, test_size = 0.3)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the issue, but `data['category'].fillna(value = 0)` basically does nothing.

Either use `inplace=True` or reassign the category column:

```py
data['category'] = data['category'].fillna(value = 0)
# or
data['category'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.fillna()`and `.dropna()` both return a copy of the DataFrame you're using them on, rather than removing NaNs in place. You could either use the `inplace=True` parameter or assign the returned value to a new variable:

```
# inplace
data['category'].fillna(value = 0, inplace=True)

# new variable
new_data = data['category'].fillna(value = 0)
```

Note, that `new_data` will only contain the `category` column if done this way. You could also overwrite the `category` column in the original `data` variable (which basically does the same as `inplace= True`):

```
data['category'] = data['category'].fillna(value = 0)
```

Comment: Yea when I look at it again it really looks funny.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There was another problem that then came up.
`'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`
the data frame has mixed data types and is shown as `dtype: object`

SOLUTION:
when applying the Label Encoder, also make sure it reads everything as string to convert it afterwards to a uniform numerical column.
`data['LE_category'] = LE.fit_transform(data['category'].astype(str, copy = True, errors = 'raise'))`
Then I could pass it to the train_test_split.